# Is it possible to invoke parent fields in constructor of child class?

Tags: scala, class, inheritance, constructor, default-value

For example if I have

```
sealed trait Foo {
   val value1 = "something"
   val value2 = "else"
}
```

Can I get something like this?

```
case class Bar(barValue = s"${super.value1} ${super.value2}") extends Foo
```

For now I have a compiler error: *value barValue is not a member of AnyRef*

PS Seems it like be easy to do, but I didn't catch why I got this compiler error
It is interesting case cause both vals are visible in constructor, but compiler fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce `value barValue is not a member of AnyRef`. I can reproduce `value value1 is not a member of AnyRef`, `value value2 is not a member of AnyRef`

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/BM6uIxGhTtmIUZoex820aA/1

A workaround is to make the case class an ordinary class and define factory methods

```
class Bar private extends Foo {
  val barValue: String = s"${value1} ${value2}"
}
object Bar {
  def apply(): Bar = new Bar
  def apply(_barValue: String): Bar = new Bar {
    override val barValue: String = _barValue
  }
}

Bar().barValue      // something else
Bar("abc").barValue // abc
```

Or it can be a case class

```
case class Bar() extends Foo {
  val barValue: String = s"${value1} ${value2}"
}
object Bar {
  def apply(_barValue: String): Bar = new Bar {
    override val barValue: String = _barValue
  }
}
```

Although there is not much sense in keeping the class a case class. `equals`, `hashcode`, `toString` etc. will be generated without respect to `barValue`.

On contrary to parent `def`s, parent `val`s should be accessed without `super`.

The error `value1 is not a member of AnyRef` is understandable. Default values of constructor parameters are typechecked in outer scope, not in parent scope. And probably you put everything into some object. `super` refers to the `super` of this outer object, i.e. `AnyRef`. And `AnyRef` doesn't have member `value1`. If you make everything top-level then the error changes to `this can be used only in a class, object, or template`.

Comment: "Default values of constructor parameters are typechecked in outer scope, not in parent scope" - this was the key of this problem. I have resolved it same way - with custom factory method in companion and companion object inheritance instead of case class inheritance

Answer (score 2):

I'd say no, because `case class Bar` creates not only `Bar` constructor (`new Bar`) but also factory method in companion object `Bar.apply`) and the later cannot access `Foo`'s constructor, even if `Bar`could.

And `Bar` can access `super` in the body, but not necessarily in the default value, since the default value... underneath is also a method in a companion.

```
Bar() // is seen by JVM as more or less as
Bar.apply(Bar.$init$1) // creates the default value and pass it to apply
```

And even if this method can use something passed from the outside (e.g. `copy` uses existing values from copied object) here you:

- fetch the default values
- call the constructor using these values
- run the body of the constructor (first `Foo`, then `Bar`)

so the default values are created long before `val value1` and `val value2` are initialized. You'd have to store is somewhere else to make them accessible.

Comment: its more interesting, cause we get the same error even if Bar is not a case class, but regular class,  and it does not provide any factory apply method for it, but the error is the same

Comment: That's the second part of the answer: defaults are evaluated before being passed into method, and `super` values are initialized within a constuctor. So default methods wouldn't even have anything to call since the reference has not been returned by a constructor and the inside of a constructor is the only place that already sees the reference to `this` (with all the `val`s being initialized just now).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use `super` in default values for case class fields. However, you can achieve the desired effect using the following approach:

```
sealed trait Foo {
  val value1 = "something"
  val value2 = "else"

  def concatValues = s"$value1 $value2"
}

case class Bar(_barValue: String = "") extends Foo {
  val barValue = if (_barValue.isEmpty) concatValues else _barValue
}
```

Comment: `equals`, `hashcode`, `toString` etc. will be generated with respect to `_barValue`, not `barValue`.